# Including default values on dynamic pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am pivoting data in a table based on date, but need to return NULL for dates with no data.

Data in [dbo].[Metrics]:

[image: Metrics]

The dynamic pivot SQL I am executing:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(1000);
SELECT @cols = 
STUFF((SELECT N'],[' + month_day
         FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(CONVERT(NCHAR(10), [Date], 126), 2)
                 FROM [Metrics]) AS O(month_day)
         ORDER BY month_day
          FOR XML PATH('')
       ), 1, 2, '') + N']';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000);

SET @sql =
N'SELECT [Key], ' + @cols +
N'  FROM (SELECT [Key], ' +
N'               RIGHT(CONVERT(NCHAR(10), [Date], 126), 2) AS month_day, ' +
N'               [Value] ' +
N'          FROM [Metrics]) AS O ' +
N'PIVOT ' +
N'(SUM([Value]) FOR month_day IN (' + @cols + N')) AS P;';

EXECUTE(@sql);
```

...and the result set that dynamic SQL returns:

[image: Pivot data]

As you can see, since I do not have data for every day of the month it is simply not returning columns for those days. How can I have it return columns 10-23 and 28-31 with NULL for each cell? It should return columns 1-31 regardless of the actual month (e.g., 31 columns even when there are less than 31 days in a given month).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you don't really need that columns to be generated dynamically, since you always want them from 1 to 31. The easier way would be hardcoding those values on your pivot, really. Anyway, here is the way you can define your columns dynamically and still get all days:

```
SELECT @cols = 
STUFF((SELECT N'],[' + CAST(number AS VARCHAR(2))
         FROM (SELECT DISTINCT number
               FROM master..[spt_values] 
               WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND 31) AS O(number)
         ORDER BY number
          FOR XML PATH('')
       ), 1, 2, '') + N']';
```

And the version you really should be using is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [Key], 
             RIGHT(CONVERT(NCHAR(10), [Date], 126), 2) AS month_day, 
             [Value] 
      FROM [Metrics]) AS O 
PIVOT (SUM([Value]) FOR month_day IN ([01],[02],[03],[04],[05],[06],[07],[08],[09],
                                      [10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],
                                      [19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],
                                      [28],[29],[30],[31])) AS P;
```

Comment: Hi Lamak, thanks for the tip. I had focused so much on using dynamic SQL I didn't stop to think that maybe I didn't need. I implemented your second solution and it works almost perfectly, _except_ it doesn't appear to be returning values for days 1-9. I would imagine this has something to do with the RIGHT() function and that leading zero, correct?

Comment: @PhillipCopley Yes, sorry, you are correct about that. Updated my answer.